# Edit button and next page link button on same gridview row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview control on page data is showing perfectly fine. I add edit button in row to update record its also working fine until I add another link in next column which redirect me to new page.
***Here is my Gridview code:***

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderWidth="2px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="1" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" GridLines="None" DataKeyNames="issue_id,pro_id" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Key#" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="issue_id">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("issue_id") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="view" CommandArgument ='<%# Eval("issue_id") %>' Text='<%# Eval("issue_id") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="pro_id" HeaderText="pro_id" SortExpression="pro_id" ReadOnly="True" Visible="False" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Project Name" SortExpression="name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="type" HeaderText="Issue Type" SortExpression="type" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="summary" HeaderText="Summary" SortExpression="summary" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="mem_id" HeaderText="Member Name" SortExpression="mem_id" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Priority" SortExpression="priority">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem>Major</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Critical</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Minor</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Cosmetic</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("priority") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="status" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="impact" HeaderText="Impact" SortExpression="impact" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Expr1" HeaderText="Submit Date" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Expr1" />
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#C6C3C6" ForeColor="Black" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4A3C8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#E7E7FF" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#C6C3C6" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#DEDFDE" ForeColor="Black" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#9471DE" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#594B9C" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#33276A" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:IHDConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT issue.issue_id, issue.pro_id, project.name, issue.type, issue.summary, issue.mem_id, issue.priority, issue.status, issue.impact, CONVERT (date, GETDATE()) AS Expr1 FROM issue INNER JOIN project ON issue.pro_id = project.pro_id" 
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [issue] SET  [mem_id] = @mem_id, [priority] = @priority, [status] = @status WHERE [issue_id] = @issue_id AND [pro_id] = @pro_id" 

            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="mem_id" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="priority" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="status" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="issue_id" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="pro_id" Type="String" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

***here is my redirect page control***

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        Response.Redirect("~/redirect.aspx?view=" + e.CommandArgument);
    }
```

***Now problem is when I click edit it redirect me to another while it is suppose to edit the record in same page.***

Comment: Try giving different command name for the button & you can use switch statement to check button command name in `RowCommand` event handler, e.g. `GridView grid = sender as GridView; switch (e.CommandName) { ... // edit or redirect here }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Row_Command to this

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CommandName.ToString() == "view")
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/redirect.aspx?view=" + e.CommandArgument);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a link when you need a link, you don't need to do postback to "redirect" the user:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Key#" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="issue_id">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("issue_id") %>'></asp:Label>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href='redirect.aspx?view=<%# Eval("issue_id") %>'><%# Eval("issue_id") %></a>            
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```